# How to see when google pub/sub completes

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

From a client, I have the following code:

```
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=json.dumps(dict(op='create_master', review_id=1273612)))
```

Is there a way to check when the item has finished being processed? If so, how would that be done? Now, I have not way of knowing if someone 'works' or not.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know that the publish has completed and Pub/Sub has received the message or do you mean that you want to know that subscribers have received the message and finished processing it?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn both -- actually. But the main thing is that the item has been finished being processed by the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To know that the message has been published successfully, you would need to look at the result of the future. The preferred way is to do this asynchronously:

```
def callback(future):
  try:
    print(future.result()) # future.result() is the message ID for the published message.
  except Exception as e:
    print("Error publishing: " + str(e))

future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=json.dumps(dict(op='create_master', review_id=1273612)))
future.add_done_callback(callback)
```

You can also do this synchronously if you want. Calling `result()` on the future will block until the result of the publish is available:

```
future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=json.dumps(dict(op='create_master', review_id=1273612)))
try:
  print(future.result()) # future.result() is the message ID for the published message.
except Exception as e:
  print("Error publishing: " + str(e))
```

There is not a built-in way to know when subscribers have finished processing the message. Requiring publishers to know when subscribers have processed messages is an anti-pattern; publishers and subscribers are meant to separate entities that aren't directly aware of each other. That being said, if you need this kind of information, the best way to do it is by setting up a second topic where your original subscribers publish messages when they have finished processing that your original publishers can subscriber to in order to know when the processing is complete.

Comment: thanks for this answer, this is really helpful. I've done a very simple database approach to store the `messageID` to keep track of when the message was received and processed. Does that approach seem reasonable?

Comment: It depends on the use case. The main difference between using Pub/Sub for acks and using a database is in the query model. If you use a database, you have to explicitly query to determine if a message has been processed. If you use Pub/Sub and a subscriber in your publisher then you get the acks as soon processing is done. If you are doing some kind of offline reconciliation process, the database would work well. But at that point, you might not need to use Pub/Sub at all; just have your publishers write to the database and have your subscribers query the database for messages to process.

Answer (score 0):

One way to set this up is to store it a database based on the `message_id`. For example, here is some example server code:

```
def callback(message):

    # Message has been received by the Server/Subscriber
    cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO pubsub (id, message, received) VALUES (%s, %s, NOW())', (message.message_id, message.data))
    connection.commit()

    # Message is processed by the Server/Subscriber
    data_obj = loads(message.data)
    _process(data_obj)

    # Message has finished being processed by the Server/Subscriber
    cursor.execute('UPDATE pubsub SET completed=NOW() WHERE id=%s', (message.message_id,))
    connection.commit()
    message.ack()
```

The client has access to the `id` via the `future.result()`, so can easily query that to see the status. This can be especially helpful if viewing statuses in a separate process (for example, if 100 long-running processes are running and we want to keep track of which have been completed).

Comment: You probably want to ack the message _after_ updating the database. Otherwise, if your subscriber process crashes before the update occurs, you will not receive the message again and therefore your entry in the database will never be marked completed.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn that makes sense -- thanks for the note (edited above).

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn is the above approach a common (or at least reasonable) pattern to keep track of pub/sub? Do most users of pub/sub care when items are sent/received, etc.?

Comment: As I mention in my answer, having publishers that need to know when messages have completed processing by subscribers is considered an anti-pattern. It couples the two in a way that is not the preferred way to use Pub/Sub. One of the main points of the paradigm is the decoupling of publishers and subscribers. So whether or not it is reasonable really depends on what the publishers (or other services) are doing with this information.